# ORA-01704: string literal too long when using JSON_Table in SQL & PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I am trying to read data from JSON and store it in Oracle DB.

I am using below code to read JSON data, but got "ORA-01704: string literal too long" error.

```
with json as (select to_clob('[    
  {
"Identifier": "999999999999999999999",
"Item_Document": "<item>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n<creationDateTime>2019-02-22T09:30:47Z</creationDateTime>\n  <documentStatusCode>ORIGINAL</documentStatusCode>\n  <documentActionCode>ADD</documentActionCode>\n  <itemIdentification>\n    <entityIdentification>HM0108775015187006</entityIdentification>\n  </itemIdentification>\n<tradeItemIdentification>\n    <gtin>00000000000000</gtin>\n  </tradeItemIdentification>\n  <description languageCode=\"en\" descriptionType=\"Short\">S-TOP BL XL</description>\n  <description languageCode=\"en\" descriptionType=\"Long\">STRAP TOP BLACK XL</description>\n  <countryOfOrigin>BD</countryOfOrigin>\n  <tradeItemBaseUnitOfMeasure>EA</tradeItemBaseUnitOfMeasure>\n  <itemHierarchyInformation>\n    <hierarchyLevelIdentifier>SKU</hierarchyLevelIdentifier>\n    <ancestry>\n      <hierarchyLevelIdentifier>OPTION</hierarchyLevelIdentifier>\n      <memberIdentifier>HM0108775015187</memberIdentifier>\n    </ancestry>\n  </itemHierarchyInformation>\n  <tradeItemMeasurements>\n    <size>\n      <descriptiveSize languageCode=\"en\">XL</descriptiveSize>\n      <sizeCode sizeCodeListCode=\"2\">6</sizeCode>\n</size>\n</tradeItemMeasurements>\n</item>",
"Number": "1"
      }  
  ]') as doc From Dual)  
  Select Item_Identification ,  
        Item_Document,
        Doc_Seqno   
  From  json_table( (Select Doc From Json) , '$[*]'
                Columns (  Item_Identification Path  '$.Identifier',
                          Item_Document      Path '$.Item_Document',
                          Doc_Seqno          Path '$.Number'    
                        )      )
```

The error message is:

> ORA-01704: string literal too long
>      01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
>      *Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
>      *Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters. Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.

[image]

Comment: The error message is quite clear: in Oracle SQL strings cannot be longer than 4000 characters. This applies to input to `to_clob()` as well. Your string is over 5000 characters long, hence the error. You will need to use a programmatic solution such as PL/SQL to solve this.

Comment: You can have string literals with up-to 32K length if you enable [extended strings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html#GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C)

Comment: Extended strings were a new feature in Oracle 12c. Which presumably you are on, because you're using `json_table()`, also new in 12c. Enabling extended strings requires taking the database out of service while a DBA runs the script and - possibly more problematic - persuading the DBAs to run the script. Neither of the two places I've worked at which upgraded to 12c enabled extended strings.